# При перезагрузке страницы распадается slick slider на мгновение, почему?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Собственно суть проблемы в вопросе (распадается это когда отображаются все слайды вниз), вот [работа](http://martynuk.esy.es/)
использую slick slider (респонсив), сборка gulp.
Как это обойти или побороть? Пробовал изменить порядок загрузки файлов, асинхронную загрузку, все бес толку. Гуглил но совета правильного не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновление**

Слайды на секунду выстраиваются столбиком в полный размер, а потом обрезаются и упаковываются в слайдер. Меню слева тоже на секунду показывается развёрнутым, а потом сворачивает свои подменю.

Полагаю, что скрипты не успевают подготовить страницу к показу.

Предложение 1. Скрипт http://martynuk.esy.es/js/script.js сначала подцепляет шрифты, а потом настраивает слайдер. Предлагаю шрифты из скрипта убрать и подцепить их как-гнибудь иначе.

```
$("head").append("<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:700|Ubuntu:400,300|Roboto+Condensed:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' />");
```

Предложение 2. Попробуйте переместить скрипт со слайдером из хвоста страницы в заголовок.

```
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: @zorro Расскажите, что у вас дальше происходит. Если дело в шрифтах, то всё понятно. А если пришлось перебрасывать скрипты в заголовок, то останавливаться нельзя, [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmartynuk.esy.es%2F) не велит. Скрипт слайдера и из хвоста страницы должен справляться с работой.